# Trouble calling a php script from mysql trigger

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am using phpmyadmin.
I am using a trigger in mysql which calls a php script after inserting something in a table.
But i cant create the trigger it shows an error msg..

> #1064 sql syntax error

Help me with this...
My code inside a trigger

```
DECLARE result INT;
SET result=select sys_exec('C:/xampp/php/php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/hello.php');
```

Comment: Or bundle the PHP with a script that will execute it (e.g. by putting the PHP in the __DATA__ section of a perl script and having the script pipe the data to a PHP interpreter). Although, to clarify, I'm providing that solution simply for variety; nl-x's solution makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like `select` (This is why you get the syntax error.)

And you should use some executable what will run that PHP file. (EG PHP.EXE)

Try something like:

```
DECLARE result INT;    
SET result = (select sys_exec('C:/path/to/PHP.EXE C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/hello.php'));
```

Comment: may i know what is C:/path/to/PHP.EXE and where i can get this php.exe file.. I am a beginner plz help me... Thanks..

Comment: @user3496195 Did you try `c:\xampp\php\php.exe` ? Does that exist on your disk ?

Comment: yes php.exe is exists... but after altering my code as you suggest i got the same error... is there any other error in my code.. editted my code in my question too...

Comment: @user3496195 I think it is missing extra parens `()` . I have edited my answer

Comment: now the trigger was created but i cant insert any thing to the table it shows error as  #1305 - FUNCTION db2.sys_exec does not exist

Comment: @user3496195 Read: http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.nl/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html