# Mysql error #1305 FUNCTION db.sys_exec does not exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am using phpmyadmin. I am using a trigger in mysql which calls a php script after inserting something in a table.
My trigger contains this.

```
DECLARE result INT;
SET result=(select sys_exec('C:/xampp/php/php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/hello.php'));
```

But i got this error while trying to insert something to the table.

```
#1305 FUNCTION db.sys_exec does not exists
```

(my database name is db)
Help me with this.Thanks.

Comment: Did you create such a function?

Comment: I don't think it's a built-in function and so the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys_exec` is not a standard mysql function. It's provided by an external UDF plugin, and must be installed separately: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme

Comment: thanks.. did i need to install lib_mysqludf_sys.sql or any other extension?

Comment: You've got to install the binary lib_mysqludf_sys.so first. Maybe you've got to compile this binary for your platform to get this up and running.

Comment: @user3496195 And please read the note of caution in the documentation https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/blob/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.html

Comment: @VMai please provide me some page which has complete installation procedure

Comment: @user3496195: A bit more readable: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/blob/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.html and have a look at the MySQL manual chapter http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html

Comment: @user3496195 This is exactly what I tried telling you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432115/trouble-calling-a-php-script-from-mysql-trigger/24432160#comment37803620_24432160 But you were too lazy to read through the link I gave you in the comments. You replied "sorry needed something clear".

Comment: @user3496195 You've got to compile this module for Windows, the binary at github isn't a windows executable, it's an [ELF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Ubuntu system and few other distributions, mysql server package contains apparmor which limits UDF functions.

> Stop apparmor

```
sudo service apparmor stop
```

> Check apparmor status

```
sudo service apparmor status
```

Even then if you get the same error, restart mysql service

> Restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Git clone the files on machine having MySQL deployed

   `git clone https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys`
2. Execute below command in the directory where the above repo is checked out :

`gcc -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -fPIC -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o lib_mysqludf_sys.so`

3. Copy the file lib_mysqludf_sys.so to /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
   The location /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ is one to be verified by running below command in mysql shell

   `SHOW VARIABLES where variable_name = 'plugin_dir';`
4. Now finally create the function in my sql shell;

   `CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';`
5. Verify that the function is created, using below command in mysql shell. This command shall return rows with one containing sys_exec  as well:

   `select * from mysql.func;`