# How to trigger the php script when the new row added in table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need an idea for my scenario.

Whenever the row is added to the database, I just need to trigger any PHP function or javascript function from the database management panel. I need that trigger from database management not from any script like AJAX.

So if I save a new row in database from my PHP script, then the trigger will call my PHP function.

Kindly help on this. I am researching on it for last two days.

Mostly I am using MySql Database.

Comment: It's not so simple. Read this https://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/triggering-shell-script-from-mysql/

Comment: *"If i save a new row in database **from my Php script**, then the trigger will call my Php function."* ... so call it from the PHP script then?

Comment: you can use cron job, fire a script using cron tab every 1 or 5 mins, the script will check for new entry in the database table and if new entry is found it will fire your script.

Comment: and for what purpose you want to fire the PHP script using mysql only?? please provide full information so one can provide a better solution if present

Comment: I just need to write a chatting script in php. I know for chatting purpose Node js is familiar. But anyway I like do that in php. If i try normally this , then i need to call ajax for every 2 secs. But I thought this is huge a call even there is no new record in my database. So i thought to trigger my php function when the new row added into my database. @NishantSolanki

Comment: @CD001 . Am sorry. I must be explained clearly. Actually I post a data from the normal form to my database. These actions are from php script. But Once the record is created on Database, then i need trigger to my php function. For Ex: You and me saving more data in single table. Without page loading and ajax , i need to know that a new record occured on my database.

Comment: @KarthikRajan then directly fire the php function after the chat row is inserted in the db, you dont need mysql trigger to do that

Comment: This may be help you..! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433851/mysql-error-1305-function-db-sys-exec-does-not-exists

Comment: This may be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433851/mysql-error-1305-function-db-sys-exec-does-not-exists